# How does layout engine work?

Tags: browser

I am REALLY curious how a web page is parsed into a DOM tree, then how the tree is rendered in a web browser. Namely,how does layout engine work?

I guess whether reading source code of a simple web browser (Webkit is too hard for me now. 
) is a feasible choice?  Thanks

Comment: Reading the source code for anything that implements current web standards is going to be a daunting task, no matter how simple the browser seems. Even CSS1 defines some rather complex rules for layout.

Comment: As Matti said, reading the source code is "a daunting task". I want to know if there are other choices to achieve the goal. thanks

Answer (score 4):

Parsing a web page into a DOM tree isn't terribly difficult to understand since (well-formed) HTML is already in a tree structure. So I don't think there's much to it except when you want to also annotate things like CSS, conditional code, and scripts into your tree.

Layout and rendering is a much more challenging problem to work out. If you're not ready to dive directly in the code, you can read their docs:

WebKit [Layout and Rendering](http://www.webkit.org/projects/layout/index.html)

Comment: WebKit seems to have removed the page you're referring to.

Answer (score 1):

You can also go to this link which has a great explanation and review of the concerned question. 
http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/internals/howbrowserswork/

Answer (score -1):

The page linked to by @binariedMe is good for understanding the narrative of when a browser parses html and then applies layout rules. If you want to get a more solid mental model of those rules, you should read http://book.mixu.net/css/